# iis: applicationhost.config in iis express

Tags: iis-express

I am using iis express 7.5. I ran the following to create a new website:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe' add site /name:comm-app /id:2 /bindings:http/*:80:comm-app.local /physicalPath:C:\G_Drive\code\iis\www\CommunicationApp\public
```

I found this config was added to the config file in my documents folder here:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

Then I decided to install the IIS console on my box and use that instead, but after installing and open the IIS console I can't see my new website. When look at the configuration editor I in the console I can see it is using the config file in the windows\system32\inetsrv.. directory:
[image]

Which config file is iis express actually using and how can I edit it with the console?

Comment: Do you have visual studios installed? I only ask because as far as I understand iis express in myDocuments is used by visual studios for websites.

Comment: I have 2012 VS express for desktop installed.

Comment: Cool well as far as editing with console i'm unsure but i can tell you applicationhost.config for iis express is the one in my documents, the other one in system32\blah\blah is (forgive the non technical wording) for the "normal" iis manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mentioned before that immediately after installing iis express I install Zend server 6 (which I believe makes some config changes).

It appears my iis express is using the config file in the system folder and is working correctly.

If anyone else is using iis express with zend server maybe this will be helpful info.